# How to change the mouse cursor in Bodhi Linux

Tags: linux, theme, cursor, enlightenment, bodhi

In Bodhi Linux, there is a poor choice of mouse cursor - only from the MOKSHA desktop theme, is it possible to change the theme of the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install `lxappearance`
2. Install `breeze-cursor-theme` (find another one if you want, see below)
3. Open `lxappearance` (press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the quick launcher and start typing lxapp...)
4. Go to cursor tab
5. Choose the theme and apply
6. Reset Moksha desktop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>

Other themes include `chameleon-cursor-theme`,
`dmz-cursor-theme`,
`moblin-cursor-theme`,
`oxygen-cursor-theme`,
`oxygen-cursor-theme-extra`, and
`xcursor-themes`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I switched back to Bodhi Linux and found my question from last year here - you answered it, solved my problem. The cursor has changed - I like the breeze snow